# Remove Columns From Grid Array With JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, grid, row, multiple-columns

Write a function `removeColumns` that accepts two arguments:

`originalGrid` (two-dimensional array)

`numColums` (number)

`removeColumns` should return a new grid with the correct number of columns removed. If `numColumns` = 1, remove one column. If `numColumns` = 2, remove two columns.

```
removeColumns([[1, 2, 3],
               [1, 2, 3],
               [1, 2, 3],
               [1, 2, 3]], 2);
/* => [[1],
       [1],
       [1],
       [1]]
*/
```

I tried:

```
function removeColumns (originalGrid, numColumns) {

  let newGrid = [];

  //if numColumns = 1, remove 1 column

  for (let col = 0; col < originalGrid.length; col ++)

    if (numColumns === 1) {
      newGrid.pop(col)
    }

  //if numColums = 2, remove 2 columns

    else if (numColumns === 2) {
      newGrid.pop(col + 1)
    }

  return newGrid;

}
```

And there are several issues with this.

I understand how to remove the last item from one array:

```
function removeItem(array) {

  let poppedArray = array.pop();

  return array;

}
```

But I do not understand how to loop through three consecutive arrays in a grid, and remove the last item from all three.

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

I think once I understand the concept of how to remove one column, I will understand how to remove two columns.

**EDIT**: [Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/FullstackAcademy/pen/ZxWLBV?editors=0010)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround:

```
function removeColumns(originalGrid, numColumns) {
  for (let i = 0; i < originalGrid.length; i++) {
    let row = originalGrid[i];
    row.reverse();
    row.splice(0, numColumns);
    row.reverse();
  }
  return originalGrid;
}
```

This way, you can remove "`numColumns`" number of elements from the start of the array, because `.splice()` always removes elements from left to right (even if you start splicing at the back of an array).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example I made that will remove one column of your choosing.  I'm not sure which of the 3 columns you want to remove when you say "remove 2 columns" but I think this should get you there.  I think what you are missing is the splice method.

```
function removeColumns(arrayOfArrays, column) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {
    arrayOfArrays[i].splice(column - 1, 1);
  }
 return arrayOfArrays;
}

var arrayOfArrays = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3],
  [1, 2, 3]
];
var results = removeColumns(arrayOfArrays, 1);

console.log(results);
```

jsFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/a5rqLbuh/

If I was doing this for raw speed I'd incorporate a library such as async to send all of the arrays off at the same time to be modified and then brought back together.  I do not think this will preserve the original order of the array of arrays, but it's something to look into.

Comment: I'm sorry but this isn't returning anything. It needs to return a new array or `arrayOfArrays`. Please see the link to the codepen to test this code: https://codepen.io/FullstackAcademy/pen/yKOgVR?editors=0010

Comment: Then just return a new array...I've edited my answer